# How to calculate pH of a 0.1 M solution of ammonium bicarbonate considering simultaneous equilibrium along with hydrolysis?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, analytical-chemistry, ph

We need to calculate the $\ce{[H+]}$ of 0.1M $\ce{(NH4+)(HCO3^-)}$ given the $\ce{k_b(NH4OH), k_{a_1}(H2CO3), k_{a_2}(HCO3^-)}$ 
The hint tells me to directly use the result $\ce{[H+]=\sqrt{k_{a_1}(\frac{k_w}{k_b}-k_{a_2})}}$
I'm trying to reach this result by systematic equilibrium analysis.
I considered the following simultaneous equilibrium: 
$\ce{NH3 +H2O<=>NH4+ +OH^-:k_b = \frac{[NH4+][OH-]}{[NH3]}}$
$\ce{H2CO3<=>H+ +HCO3-:k_{a_1}=\frac{[H+][HCO3-]}{[H2CO3]}}$ 
$\ce{HCO3^-<=>H+ +CO3^{2-}:k_{a_2}=\frac{[H+][CO3^{2-}]}{[HCO3^-]}}$ 
$\ce{H2O(l)<=>H+ +OH-:k_w=[H+][OH-]}$ 
I'm not sure how I shall proceed further. I also tried to write the following charge balance equation: 
$\ce{[NH4+] +[H+]=[HCO3-] +2[CO3^{2-}] +[OH-]}$ 
But in this case, wouldn't the $\ce{[NH4+],[HCO3-]}$ cancel out as they both are equal to 0.1M? Upon solving the charge balance I don't reach the given result. Where am I going wrong? How do I derive the formula?

Comment: It reduces to the generally applicable substitution method of solving the set of n nonlinear equations for n variables, with justified applying simplifications based of strong inequalities. The starting points are all equilibrium equations, the ion charge balance equation and total substance concentration equations. I highly recommend to perform formal symbol substitution by single-letter variables. BTW there is no NH4OH in water, it is decades old myth.

Comment: *wouldn't the [NH4+],[HCO3−] cancel out as they both are equal to 0.1M?*  They will hydrolyze and not in the same extent. [NH3] + [NH4+] = [H2CO3] + [HCO3-] + [CO3^2-]

Comment: @Poutnik I understand that it comes down to solving a system of equations, but I think either my method or the result given in the problem has an issue. If I can get the chemistry right, then the equations won't be a problem. About the $\ce{NH4OH}$, so should I edit that equilibrium to $\ce{NH3 +H2O<=>NH4+ +OH-}$? Would that be correct? But then how would I use the $\ce{k_b(NH4OH)}$?

Comment: the Kb, or pKb (about 4.75) remains it is just NH4OH(aq) versus NH3(aq).  N atom is unable to form 5 bonds, having only one 2s and three 2p orbitals. //  [NH3] + [NH4+] = 0.1 M   AND   [H2CO3] + [HCO3-] + [CO3^2-]  = 0.1 M

Comment: @Poutnik Okay, got it! What I did was I put the values in the given result to verify if it was correct and in the end I ended up getting that it'll only be true if $\ce{[HCO3-]=[NH4+]}$. Is the result wrong?

Comment: There is multiple "right" results, based on the chosen set of approximations. One of the possible is consideration $\ce{HCO3- + NH4+ <=> H2CO3 + NH3}$, with such ratios of respective forms that belong to the same pH, according to the respective dissociation constant. Then your suggested equation is approximately valid. But results of approximations should be checked how well they fit to exact equations.

Comment: @Poutnik We need to consider $\ce{k_b(NH3)=1.75 \times 10^{-5} M, k_{a_1}(H2CO3)=4.2 \times 10^{-7} M, k_{a_2}(HCO3^-)=4.2 \times 10^{-11} M}$, I've tried manipulating the seven equations and approximating and neglecting terms but it is becoming super messy and I can't quite figure out how to reach the formula they've used. I could get the correct answer just by brute-forcing the equations but my aim here is to reach the result mentioned in the problem's hint/solution. Considering the values I just mentioned, can I reach the result? Any hints would be great, thanks so much!